# Will myopic vision be improved while diving?

Tags: optics, refraction, vision

Why does my myopic vision improve under water while wearing a diving mask, compared to my normal vision on land?

Comment: How many negative diopters is your prescription?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/250363/  and this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83480/