# Why do objects appear larger in water?

Tags: visible-light, water, refraction

Why does it look bigger when we see something in the water?

Comment: There are some nice answers/discussions in SE which fully answered your question in detail. See here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/83480/why-would-an-object-appear-a-different-size-when-in-water#:~:text=Since%20air%20has%20an%20index,they%20would%20look%20in%20air.